# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement while showing events in full calendar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Im trying to showing dynamically showing events in full calendar in my project. There is a error i didn't understand what the reason behind this ,However when i hard code events array its working fine.

Calendar  Jquery  Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        events: [
            eventList()
        ]
    });
```

Ajax Call

```
function eventList(){
    $.ajax({
        url :'/calendarMaintenanceData',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {                                                                                      
                {
                    id:item.id,
                    title:item.machinecode,
                    start:item.estimated_maintenance_date
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
}
```

Error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eventList` needs to put all the events into an array. You can use `$.map` instead of `$.each` to do this.

```
    success:function(data){
        return $.map(data, function (item) {  
            return {                                                                                    
                id:item.id,
                title:item.machinecode,
                start:item.estimated_maintenance_date
            };
        }); 
    }
```

However, this still won't. The problem is that `$.ajax` is asynchronous, so the return value of the callback function won't be returned to the `fullCalender` function. You need to call `fullCalendar` in the callback function after creating the array.

```
function eventList(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url :'/calendarMaintenanceData',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            callback($.map(data, function (item) {                                                                                      
                return {
                    id:item.id,
                    title:item.machinecode,
                    start:item.estimated_maintenance_date
                };
            }); 
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    eventList(function(events) {
        $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            events: events
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `$.each()` you have to assign a variable to a object defined like this

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {                                                                                      
                     var someobject =  {
                        id:item.id,
                        title:item.machinecode,
                        start:item.estimated_maintenance_date
                      };
                   });
```

Comment: i assign variable after this new error show


{
TypeError: d is undefined
 

...form(d)),a.extend(i,d),e&&(i.source=e),i._id=d._id||(void 0===d.id?"_fc"+tb++:d....

 }

Comment: have you defined a variable d somewhere because it's not in a code you posted

Comment: No ,I'm not using d variable any where

Comment: i think you need objects as a array in events in fullcalender but your function eventList() is not returning anything

Comment: this error has been removed when i used function  in events like this - 

 events: function() {
           
            eventList();
            
      },